# Как взять элементы из <input type="text">?

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается использовать массив из Input type="text" в функции. Ввожу в input несколько чисел через запятую и нужно чтоб функция сравнила их всех и вывела наибольшее число.

```
 <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Введите число">
<input type="button" name="max1" onclick="maximum()" value="max"><br><br>
<div id="ggg"></div>
<script>
    function maximum(){
    document.getElementById('ggg').innerHTML = Math.max(input1.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input1.value` - дает нам строку формата `"1,2,3"`. Чтобы найти максимальное число, нам надо поделить строку на числа с помощью `split(',')`, который вернет массив фомата `['1', '2', '3']`.

```js
function maximum() {
  ggg.innerHTML = Math.max(...input1.value.split(','));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Введите число">
<input type="button" name="max1" onclick="maximum()" value="max">
<br><br>
<div id="ggg"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А почему **точки** перед input.value.split(',') важны? Без них код не работал.

Comment: @BooBoo, эти три точки `...` называются [деструктуризацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Функция `Math.max()` принимает много параметров, но как числа. А без точек мы передавали массив. Вот и функция не могла понять, что искать, потому что вместо числа получила массив. Чтобы функция поняла, надо использовать троеточие, что означает расспаковку массива. Т.е. мы как бы пишем `Math.max('1', '2', '3', ...)`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.

Comment: @BooBoo, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

```js
function maximum() {
  ggg.innerHTML =  Math.max.apply(Math, input1.value.split(','));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Введите число" value="123,456,321">
<input type="button" name="max1" onclick="maximum()" value="max"><br><br>
<div id="ggg"></div>
```

Comment: Шок. Впервые узнал, что можно не писать `document.getElementByid...`, а просто взять название id.

Comment: @entithat: дык, ID же всегда глобальным был, не?

Comment: @UModeL, даже в мыслях такого не было. Господи, а я везде писал этот document... Век живи, век учись...

Comment: @entithat: но, тем не менее `getElementById` тоже нужен. Рекомендую найти внятную статью про него. Я заинтересовался после [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47511581/10179415) на SO, а раньше тоже не сталкивался и сильно не углублялся.